# is this what is happening in this react code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

this is an experimental code to represent probable misunderstanding of how react works
https://jsfiddle.net/Dr_Coder/h6da2jku/78/

```js
const App = () => {
      const {
        useState,
        useEffect
      } = React;
    
    const [firstCount, setFirstCount] = useState(0);
    const [secondCount, setSecondCount] = useState(0)
    
    const increment = () => setFirstCount(firstCount + 1)
    useEffect(() => {
     if(firstCount >= 1) setSecondCount(firstCount)
     
     const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setFirstCount(0)
     }, 1000);
     
     return () => clearTimeout(timer)
    }, [firstCount, secondCount]);
    
      return (<div className = "app" >
       <button onClick={increment}>click  {firstCount}</button>
       <p>{secondCount}</p>
      < /div>
      )
    }
    
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<div id="root">

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

in my mind i think this happens:

1 - clicking the button and  this will increment `firstCount`

2 - rendering with the new value of `firstCount`

3 - useEffect will work because there is a change in `firstCount` dependency value

4 - the condition is true and this will change the value of `secondCount` to be equal to the value of `firstCount`

5 - this will render component again with the new value of `secondCount`

6 - timer finishes, and set `firstCount` to 0, this will render component again

7 - after render `useEffect` will work, the condition is false, nothing happens

Is this what really happening in the code, the life cycle of a react component is overwhelming, and i hope someone clarify what is exactly happening in the code!

Comment: Yes, your description fits. "What's really happening" is a very very complex broad topic, it would be good if you could limit that to the functionality of one single function or so.

Comment: @JonasWilms - *Mostly*, they missed out a couple of important things I was explaining in my answer when the question was closed.

Comment: but why the question closed?? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Seems right, I'm not really sure what you're asking. The example you've written is very clear. Did you expect a different behaviour from this code?

Comment: @CodeEagle - I didn't vote to close it, and did vote to reopen it. But the close reason given was that it needed more focus.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Quickly answer before it is closed

Comment: @t.j. well, but which things are important and which aren't? This is too broad, but I certainly won't stop you from answering :)

Comment: @CodeEagle You might want to explain your concerns about your explanation

Comment: @mplungjan

I read alot about life cycle in react but it is overwhelming to me, so i created an example and asking if my understanding is right, thanks

Comment: @JonasWilms - I agree it's really a judgement call about whether it needs more focus. I can see the argument. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's mostly right, but:

- You missed out a small bit prior to #1: The first render will call the `useEffect` callback. The condition is false, but a timer is set; unless you do something within a second, `firstCount` is set to `0` by the timer callback.
- The "nothing happens" isn't true in #7 - the `useEffect` callback still starts a timer, and a second later, the timer still fires. You just don't notice because it's setting the value `firstCount` already has (0). You can see that if you step through in the debugger or use some `console.log`s:

```js
const {
    useState,
    useEffect
} = React;

const App = () => {

    console.log("App called");

    const [firstCount, setFirstCount] = useState(0);
    const [secondCount, setSecondCount] = useState(0);

    const increment = () => setFirstCount(firstCount + 1);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect callback");
        if (firstCount >= 1) {
            console.log("useEffect callback - setSecondCount to " + firstCount);
            setSecondCount(firstCount);
        }

        console.log("useEffect callback - start timer");
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("timer fired, setFirstCount(0)");
            setFirstCount(0)
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            console.log("useEffect cleanup callback, cancel timer [if it hasn't run]");
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, [firstCount, secondCount]);

    return (
        <div className = "app">
        <button onClick={increment}>click  {firstCount}</button>
        <p>{secondCount}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App/> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<div id="root">

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You can learn more about the React component lifecycle, specifically in regard to hooks, in this article by Dan Abramov. It's ostensibly about `useEffect`, but really it's about the component lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense